# Does Java support chained inequality comparisons such as (5 < i < 10)?

Tags: java, comparison, operators

Is there any operator or trick for such operation?
Or is it necessary to use this:

```
if (5 < i && i < 10) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `i<10` condition ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no such thing in Java (unless you work with booleans).

The `5<i`results in a boolean on the left side on `<10` which the compiler dislikes.

Answer (score 24):

You cannot chain inequalities. You can, however, define a static boolean method `isInRange(value, low, high)` that will perform such a check.

Some other languages, like Python or [Icon](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/icon/), allow this notation.

Comment: Perhaps the parameters should be ordered as `isInRange(low, value, high)` e.g. `isInRange(5, i, 10)`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid chained inequalities are unsupported in Java at this time. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644044/chained-inequality-notation-in-programming-languages) post for languages which do.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a single comparison but is more complicated than its worth usually.

```
if (i - (Integer.MIN_VALUE + 6) < Integer.MIN_VALUE + (10 - 6))
```

This uses underflow to adjust all the value 5 and below to be a large positive value.

The only reason you would use this is as a micro-optimisation.

Comment: You wrote `6` twice, probably something OP wants to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

## Range

Comparisons cannot be chained in Java.

The standard way for doing a range check is to use either [*Guava Ranges*](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained):

```
import com.google.common.collect.Range;
...
    if(Range.open(5, 10).contains(x)){
```

or Apache Commons Lang (it provides only closed ranges, though):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.Range;
...
    if(Range.between(5 + 1, 10 - 1).contains(x)){
```

Answer (score 1):

a < x < b is equivalent to (x-a)(x-b)<0, or if x is an expression you only wanna calculate once,

(x - (a+b)/2) ^ 2 < (b-a)^2 / 4

Same deal with two nonstrict equalities. I don't think there's a way to deal with one strict and one nonstrict equality, however (unless x is an integer).