# The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int

Tags: java, processing

I am new to processing and I am having trouble with this. I keep getting an error message for the bolded part of the code below. Is my syntax wrong?

```
void block(int x, int y, int s, color tinto) {
    fill(tinto);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        triple(x, y+i*s, s, tinto);
    }
    if (0 < i < 3 && 6 < i < 9) {  // HERE
        tinto = 255;
    }
    else {
        tinto = tinto - 200;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which error message are you getting?

Comment: `if (0<i<3 && 6<i<9){` isn't legal. Not sure what you're trying to do but if you want to say that `i` should be between 0 and 3 for example, then you need to write it as `if (i > 0 && i < 3)` and go from there. You can have as many &&s or ||s as you need.

Comment: You'll have to explain to us what you are trying to do. Even if Java had a range operator like some are assuming you are trying to do, `0<i<3 && 6<i<9` would never evaluate to true. (`i` can't be between 0 and 3 and also be between 6 and 9 at the same time...)

Comment: This doesn't even make sense because `i` cannot be between 0 and 3 and between 6 and 9 simultaneously.

Comment: Related: [Java chained inequality if (5<i<10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658343/java-chained-inequality-if-5i10)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, to check if a variable is in a range you have to divide the statement into two parts, like this:

```
if (0 < i && i < 3 && 6 < i && i < 9){

}
```

This specific code will never be true, however, because you're asking for it to be in two different ranges. Perhaps you meant to check for either range?

```
if (0 < i && i < 3 || 6 < i && i < 9){

}
```

Note the || or operator instead of the && and operator.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is not valid, and I think you're expression is wrong anyway. You say `i` has to be within a range AND within another. I think you mean to write that it could be between one OR the other.

Example of valid syntax: instead of `0 < i < 3`, write `i > 0 && i < 3`.

Try this:

```
if ( (i > 0 && i < 3) || (i > 6 && i < 9) )
```

Note that the following (which is what you were trying to do apparently) will never be evaluated to `true` because it cannot be within both ranges.

```
if ( (i > 0 && i < 3) && (i > 6 && i < 9) ) // incorrect
```

Comment: My expression is definitely wrong... I tried the vaild syntax and now the program runs but it does not change the color of the 3x3 block in the middle.

Comment: @kairoseno We can't diagnose your program because we don't know anything about it. If you still have problems, post another question on this site with all of the relevant code needed. And if my answer answered your current question, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark to the left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't valid java expression. Try:

```
if (0<i && i<3 && 6<i && i<9){
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different problems with this code snippet.  First, you have defined the 'i' variable as in "int" inside of the for loop.  This instance of 'i' is no longer defined once you exit that for loop -- so the if statement below does not refer to that instance.  To overcome this, define 'i' *before* the for loop...

```
int i;
for ( i=0; i<3; I++ ) {
    ...
}
if ( i ...
```

which brings me to the second error.  The syntax "0 < i < 3" is not correct.  In c/c++ the operators are executed one at a time ... so in this case the first "<" operator will be evaluated as "0 < i" and the result will be a Boolean (which will always be 'true' in your particular code snippet).  But the important point is that the result is a Boolean.  Next the code will attempt to evaluate that result with the next part of the statement -- "true < 3", which just doesn't make any sense, and so that receives a compiler error.
    In your code snippet, there is no exit to the for loop until the value of i reaches 3, so this second "if" statement is unneeded. But if you *did* want to test to see whether i was between 1 and 2 (inclusive), then you would have to break those up into individual tests...

```
if ( 0 < i && i < 3 ...
```

Lastly ... if the value of i is between 1 and 2 (inclusive), then it cannot also be between 7 and 8 (inclusive) .. therefore the if statement as you coded it will always be false even after we correct the syntax.